# Proguard. Отключение объединения классов с одинаковым classpath

Tags: java, jar, proguard

У меня есть два скина для моего приложения расположенных в двух jar, в обоих есть такой класс:
`ru.project.skin.SkinLoader`. Название и путь одинаковый, но содержимое разное.
Я запускаю proguard, указывая в конфиге:

```
injars "../skin-one.jar"
outjars "../proguard/skin-one.jar"
injars "../skin-two.jar"
outjars "../proguard/skin-two.jar"
```

На выходе получается, что у двух jar содержимое класса SkinLoader одинаково и взято из skin-one.jar, а код из SkinLoader в skin-two.jar утерян.
Как этого избежать и сохранить содержимое классов?

Пробовал в конфиге указывать:

```
-keep class ru.project.skin.**
-keepclassmembers class ru.project.skin.** {
    *;
}
```

Но не помогло. Также читал
[офф документацию](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage), ничего подходящего не нашел. Пробовал запускать с

```
-dontshrink
-dontobfuscate
-dontoptimize
```

Все равно код затирается.